# What is a good way to balance the pros and cons from using Redux?

Tags: react-native

Of course Redux provides us a very excellent solution for managing the states.

However, it's hard to handle async dispatches and a global state may not be needed for many components in the project.

Is it possible to have a solution can fulfill the basic usage of redux and also handle async problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely check [Redux-Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) or [Redux-Service](https://github.com/ThatBean/redux-service) first.

There are many tutorials and real examples with using Redux-Saga so I'll not talk a lot about it.

Redux-Service is written by one of my colleagues and has been applied to our production environment for a long time. The solution behind is that by combining the idea of Redux-Saga, Redux-Thunk and the generator in JavaScript, Redux-Service `offers an experimental way to handle (highly mutable || remote) data source && async logic in Redux.`

If you are experienced with backend development framework like Express, you will be familiar with the concept of middlewares. And here you go. The ideas of Express middleware and Redux-Service are pretty similar.

Check more from the document and try to do some mini project with it should be more helpful than words.

Comment: https://github.com/infinitered/ignite provide a good way to start with redux-saga on react-native

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Redux-Tunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), in case you has not done it yet.

Given it's nice feature of returning the value of the inner function as the result of `dispatch` invocation and combining this feature with `Promises` makes it super easy to orchestrate asynchronous state updates.

They have pretty clear explanation of the concept under [Compostion section](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition) of their doc.